# Pyspark DataFrame Returns Inconsistent Result

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, pyspark

I am running some codes on Databricks platform and encountered a super werid problem that the results returned by the same dataframe were inconsistent. Here comes my code:

Firstly, I want to show the records satisfying a specefic criteria:
[image]

As highlighted in the above figure, the record with "unique_key" 26486 matches my criteria. And now I want to query this record inversely by its "unique_key":
[image]

**The super werid thing happens, what was returned by the same dataframe "sdf" was inconsistent with the previous result: the highlighted contents were different except for the "unique_key"**.

I have been struggling in this problem for a while and don't know if it is a bug of pyspark. Anyone has ideas on that? THX.

Comment: Are you sure your `unique_key` is *unique*? Spark surely can't make that up.

Comment: Hi @ernest_k, the `unique_key` here is created by `monotonically_increasing_id()` and in my understanding, it makes no difference whether it is unique since even though it is not unique, the record appears in the first query should apprear in the second query, too. But now, it just returned one record with the different values of the other columns.

Comment: Could you please post your code how `sdf` is created, including the call of `monotonically_increasing_id()`?